# unable to display image using jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I created a separate model for users to upload a profile pic.

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):

profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

html

```
 <img src="/images/{{ image.profilepic }}"/>
```

all I am getting back is a empty canvas with an image icon
I should note the images are uploading to the folder just not displaying

Comment: where it is saving uploade img, static or media folder

Comment: I have a folder called images thats where its saving them too @ManojTolagekar

Comment: I think it is automatically generated with media folder right?

Comment: I don't think so. I have a blog model that uploads images to the same folder but I had to manually create the folder.

Comment: when you add upload_to="images/" to model field, it created automatically as media/images, you don't need to create image folder seperately.

Comment: Just delete that image folder which is you created and upload any image in front-end. And see media folder will generate automatically along with image folder, only if image is saved in db

Comment: You can use the `url` attribute of the image field so long as your media settings are correct - `src="{{ image.profilepic.url }}"`

Answer (score 1):

I think need to add .url like this

```
<img src="/images/{{ image.profilepic.url }}"/>
```